# Filedrop JSON Response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am using the filedrop plugin for jquery to upload images to imgur on my site. The PHP script returns `{"status":"Imgur code: cZ8gH"}`

I want to return this as an alert but I can't figure out how to do it?

I currently have this

```
    uploadFinished:function(i,file,response){
        $.data(file).addClass('done');
        var jsonobj = $.parseJSON(response);
        alert(jsonobj.status);
        // response is the JSON object that post_file.php returns
    }
```

But it is not working?

Comment: Perhaps the response is already parsed. Does `response.status` work?

Comment: It's always better to use a browser with a console (or Firebug Lite) and call `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Comment: @Thomas Perhaps you should make an answer from your comment so you can be credited for this? ) Because it is an answer: by default (if no dataType is sent in ajax call params) jQuery tries to guess the response type from its content - and if turns out to be JSON, automatically parse it. )

Comment: If I read the docs correctly jquery only uses the mime type and not the content to dermine the type of the response. It looks like in this case it might be the plugin that parses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the filedrop plugin but when no dataType is specified jQuery tries to parse the ajax response using MIME type of the response.

So the response might already have been parsed by jQuery.

Try using

```
response.status
```

To help in debugging it's always better to use a browser with a console (or Firebug Lite) and call

```
console.log
```

instead of using `alert` especially because `console` can print objects

Thanks to [@raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229023/raina77ow)